# Where is the shadow catcher in blender 3.5?

Tags: shadows, shadowcatcher

I can't seem to find the shadow catcher in blender 3.5. Did they moved it or is it a bug and it's just not there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean this?  *Object Properties* -> *Visibility* pane

You have to be using *Cycles* engine.

[image]